# Unsucceedable cast when declaring CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-preferences, checkboxpreference

After declaring a `CheckboxPreference` in my activity for my app's settings, a warning appears for `as` in the line '`val mCheckBoxPreference = findPreference("preference_a") as CheckBoxPreference`'. What should be done so that the cast does succeed?

> This cast can never succeed

**app_preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="preference_a"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="Preference A"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**fragment class**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference
import android.preference.Preference
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import android.util.Log

class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences)

        val mCheckBoxPreference = findPreference("preference_a") as CheckBoxPreference
        mCheckBoxPreference.onPreferenceChangeListener = this
    }

    // declaring PreferenceXchangeListener
    private var mPreferenceXchangeListener: PreferenceXchangeListener? = null

    // declaring PreferenceXchangeListener in order to communicate with Activities
    interface PreferenceXchangeListener {
        fun onXchange(value:Boolean)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        // on attach - assign parent Activity as PreferenceXchangeListener
        try
        {
            mPreferenceXchangeListener = context as MySettingsFragment.PreferenceXchangeListener
        }
        catch (e:ClassCastException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach::::: PreferenceXchangeListener must be set in parent Activity")
        }
    }

    override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference, newValue:Any):Boolean {
        val preferenceKey = preference.key

        if (preferenceKey == "preference_a")
        {
            (preference as CheckBoxPreference).isChecked = newValue as Boolean
            // executing parent Activity's callback with the new value
            mPreferenceXchangeListener!!.onXchange(newValue)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = MySettingsFragment::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

**activity class**

```
class MySettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MySettingsFragment.PreferenceXchangeListener {
    private var mCurrentValue: Boolean? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        mCurrentValue = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("preference_a", false)
        if (mCurrentValue as Boolean)
        {
            setTheme(R.style.MyDarkAppCompatTheme)
        }
        else
        {
            setTheme(R.style.MyLightAppCompatTheme)
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mysettings)

        val settingsFragment = MySettingsFragment()
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, settingsFragment)
                .commit()

        val myActionBar = actionBar

        if (myActionBar != null)
        {
            myActionBar.setTitle(R.string.settings)                
            myActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK))
        }
    }

    override fun onXchange(value:Boolean) {
        if (value !== mCurrentValue)
        {
            mCurrentValue = value
            recreate()
        }
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                val intent = parentActivityIntent
                intent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                onBackPressed()
                return true
            }

            else ->
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = MySettingsActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You have to change the import to `android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference`.

There are two versions of `CheckBoxPreference`:

- `android.preference.CheckBoxPreference`, which was added in API level 1 and has `android.preference.Preference` as ancestor class
- `android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference` which belongs to the support library and has `android.support.v7.preference.Preference` as ancestor class

Your `Fragment` extends from `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, so `findPreference()` will return a `android.support.v7.preference.Preference`. Since you can't cast *support* `Preference` classes to their *non support* equivalents, Android Studio is showing the error message "This cast can never succeed" when you attempt to cast to the *non support* `CheckBoxPreference`.